# How to change "From" email address in "Note to customer" woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When edit an order, admin can send an message to customer. But at, wc-settings&tab=email it's using "From" address to sent mail eg: no-repy@gmail.com
and i dont want use this in "Note to Customer".

I mean, with "Note to Customer" function will use other mail like noteToCustomer@gmail.com only.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'change_reply_to_email', 10, 3 );
function change_reply_to_email( $header, $email_id, $order ) {
    $name  = 'Pickashirt';
    $email = 'noteToCustomer@gmail.com';
    if( $email_id == 'customer_note' ){
        $headers  .= 'From: ' . $name . ' ' . "<" . $email . ">";        
    }
    return $header;
}
```

Hope will get help on this.
Many Thanks,
Tin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will add an additional reply-to email address

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'change_reply_to_email', 10, 3 );
function change_reply_to_email( $header, $email_id, $order ) {
    $name  = 'Your Name';
    $email = 'notetocustomer@gmail.com';
    if( $email_id == 'customer_note' ){
        $header .= 'Reply-to: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . ">\r\n";
    }
    return $header;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to change the from address, then you can use the following code.

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_address', 'change_from_email', 10, 3 );
function change_from_email( $from, $email ) {
    if( $email->id == 'customer_note' ){
        $from = 'notetocustomer@gmail.com';
    }
    return $from;
}
```

Comment: Hi melvin,
First code working but not what i am expect. Second code function not working.

Comment: what i want - can change From emaill sender. First code not help me change From address mail

Comment: What is your actual requirement ? `Reply to` email or `from` email ?

Comment: From Email - just edit my question - please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @TranVanTin I have updated my code. Tested and this works.

Comment: thank so much - your code working fine - just one question. Its only effect note to customer only if so this is what i want. Thanks

Comment: @TranVanTin Yes. This affects only the customer note email. The code `$email->id == 'customer_note'` check is to make sure the email is customer note email. Please accept as answer and upvote

Comment: yes i was ready upvote for you but stackoverflow said my question [duplicate]. I dont know how to solve it